# Google TV SDK for Android

Tags: android, google-tv

Is the Google TV SDK for Android available now to download ?

Comment: If you find it tell me ! hehehe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Per the FAQ](http://code.google.com/tv/web/faq.html#howandroidsdk):

> How do I get the Google TV SDK for
>   Android?
>
> ```
> The Google TV SDK add-on will be freely available to developers.
> Please sign-up on www.google.com/tv to stay informed about availability.
> ```

If you visit [www.google.com/tv](http://www.google.com/tv) there's a "Developers" link at the top. [The developers page](https://developers.google.com/tv/) simply says "More information coming soon" and links to a page where you can sign up to receive updates about availability.

So it appears the answer is no, you cannot currently get it.

---

**Edit (8/23/2011):** Google has released what it is referring to as a "preview version" of the Google TV SDK add-on. You can find instructions for setting up a development environment [here](http://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_setup_android.html) and you can [read the announcement](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/preview-of-google-tv-add-on-for-android.html) on the Android Developers Blog.

Comment: Note that there's a Google I|O 2011 conference session scheduled on writing apps for Google TV, so there's a slightly increased odds that it'll show up sometime in the not-too-distant future. Maybe. Did I hedge enough in this comment? :-)

Comment: Seems like they've taken down those links, none of them are working.

Comment: @clide313: The developers link moved (fixed that one), but the rest work fine for me.